# UIStackView as a root view of a XIB

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, interface-builder, xib

I'd like to create a small `UIViewController` that contains an `UITextField` and a `UILabel` going one after the other.

I've decided to use an instance of `UIStackView` to lay out the subviews.

However, I have to add a `UIStackView` as a subview of the parent `UIView` in XIB.

Is it possible to configure XIB the way that the root view of the controller would be of a certain class, eliminating the need for the extra view?

I've attached the current view hierarchy. I'd like to get rid completely off the topmost `View`.

[image: current view hierarhchy]

Comment: At least in code that should be possible. But interface builder has many limitations like for instance you even can't add subviews to components like image views or buttons which might seem completely normal thing to do. Anyway, this is usually a very very very bad idea in the first place. A bad example of this exactly is `UITableViewController` which uses `UITableView` as base view of the view controller. You can not imagine the amount of frustration that this has produced. In my opinion avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you need just to set the stackview as the the root view of your view controller as following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

1- create new file -> under the user interface choose "Empty"
[image]

2- then you will get an empty XIB
[image]

3- after that you can add your UIStackView from the UI Component picker

4- put your UITextField and UILabel
[image]

5- finally create your .swift file and wire it up with your XIB